# Lucene 8.3 migration

Tags: java, lucene, migration

I'm trying to migrate Lucene v6.6.6 -> 8.3.1
Method MultiFields.getFields was removed. Could anybody tell me how could I receive all Terms stored by DirectoryReader?

Present code:

```
final Terms terms = MultiFields.getFields(directoryReader()).terms(FIELD_SOURCE);
    if (terms != null) {
        final TermsEnum termsEnum = terms.iterator();
        BytesRef text;

        while ((text = termsEnum.next()) != null) {
            final String sourceId = text.utf8ToString().toUpperCase();
            resultSet.add(sourceId);
        }
```

Wish to return sourceId HashSet, but maybe there is a dofferent way to get this data?